# Is there any similar as input_tag select_tag in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am new in Symfony2, I have already work with symfony 1.2 and 1.4 and there was options in forms like input_tag(), input_hidden_tag() and select_tag()

My question is if is there any function that works similiar to those functions

I have already read this link

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

There are forms helpers showed in the next link

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_0/en/10-Forms

Comment: Can you try to explain what these functions achieve?

Comment: I have already added a link when you can see how it works in template side.